# Clear old data in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I'm using Prometheus and Grafana  for monitoring the servers.
Grafana data were stored in `/home/user/data` folder.

This folder occupied the majority of the file system .

Need to remove the old data in Grafana `data` folder ( Data which is older than a month )

Answer (score 11):

Grafana does not save data from Prometheus. It queries Prometheus and displays UI. In this case, you would have to look at purging Prometheus data.

Prometheus by default has a 15 day retention period. But this could be adjusted by the -storage.local.retention flag to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

According to official [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/storage/) of Prometheus:

> --storage.tsdb.path: This determines where Prometheus writes its database. Defaults to data/
>
> --storage.tsdb.retention: This determines when to remove old data. Defaults to 15d

If your Grafana's datasource is prometheus, you can stop prometheus, delete content of this path, start prometheus again and restart grafana
If you have data for more than 15 days, then you set storage retention. reducing it to less value will delete the data before the specified time.