# Don't show data from redeployed pod in Grafana using promQL

Tags: grafana, prometheus, promql

I have a PromQL query that is looking at max latency per quantile and displays the data in Grafana, but it shows data from a pod that is redeployed and no longer exists. The pod is younger than the staleness period of 15 days.

Here's the query: `max(latency{quantile="..."})`

The max latency found is from the time it was throttling, and shortly after it got redeployed and went back to normal, and now I want to look only at the max latency of what is currently live.

All the info that I found so far about staleness says it should be filtering behind the scenes, but doesn't look like it's happening in the current setup and I cannot figure out what should I change.

When adding manually in the query the specific instance ID - it works well, but the ID will change once it gets redeployed: `max(latency{quantile="...", exported_instance="ID"})`

Here is a long list of similar questions I found, some are not answered, some are not asking for the same. The ideas that I did find that are somewhat relevant but don't solve the problem in a sustainable way are:

#### Suggestions from the links below that were not helpful

- change staleness period, won't work because it affects the whole system
- restart Prometheus, won't work because it can't be done every time a pod is redeployed
- list each graph per machine, won't work with a `max` query

#### Links to similar questions

- [How do I deal with old collected metrics in Prometheus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324007/how-do-i-deal-with-old-collected-metrics-in-prometheus)
  Switch prom->elk: log based monitoring
- [Get data from prometheus only from last scrape iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53226399/get-data-from-prometheus-only-from-last-scrape-iteration)
  Staleness is a relevant concept, in Singlestat it shows how to use only current value
- [Grafana dashboard showing deleted information from prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54731984/grafana-dashboard-showing-deleted-information-from-prometheus)
  Default retention is 15 days, hide machines with a checkbox
- [How can I delete old Jobs from Prometheus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704117/how-can-i-delete-old-jobs-from-prometheus)
  Manual query/restart
- [grafana variable still catch old metrics info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53292892/grafana-variable-still-catch-old-metrics-info)
  Update prometheus targets
- [Clear old data in Grafana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630658/clear-old-data-in-grafana)
  Delete with prometheus settings
- https://community.grafana.com/t/prometheus-push-gateway/18835
  Not answered
- https://www.robustperception.io/staleness-and-promql
  Explains how new staleness works without examples

#### The end goal

is displaying the max latency between all sources that are live now, dropping data from no longer existing sources.

Comment: This question seems to be confusing retention and staleness. Can you give example time series, and what output you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use auto generated metric named `up` to isolate your required metrics from others. You can easily determine which metric sources are offline from `up` metric.

> up{job="", instance=""}: 
>   1 if the instance is healthy, i.e. reachable, 
>   or 0 if the scrape failed.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am familiar with this part of the Job Instances documentation (prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances) and cannot see how it fits with the syntax that I have: It's just a quantile on a latency here. 

The combinations I tried do not work, but maybe you have a suggestion?